# How to set up my apple watch to track my sleep without or beyond bedtime?

Tags: sleep-wake, apple-watch

My sleep schedule is chaotic and I can go sleep at any hour of the day. But Apple Watch is tracking sleep only at bedtime which can’t exceed 20 hours. Moreover, I’d like not to define all my day as a bedtime. So, I just want my sleep to be tracked independently from the bedtime. Is it possible?